# How to add search icon in a textbox using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[google search http://tech-and-teaching.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/firefox-search.png](http://tech-and-teaching.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/firefox-search.png)

How do I create a search box like the one highlighted(top of the image) using bootstrap? The magnifying glass icon should be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create a button and input next to each other in a form and then using CSS absolutely position the button on top of the form.

Style the button (bootstrap includes a number of useful icons) to look like the magnifying glass and there you go!

-Edit-

Some example code, as I'm feeling generous.

```
<div id="form-master">
<form method="post">
    <div id="search-box">
        <input type="text" name="search" />
    </div>

    <div id="search-button">
        <input type="submit" name="run" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#form-master {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
}

#search-box {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
width: 190px;
height: 20px;
padding: 5px;
}

#search-button {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
right: 5px;
z-index: 5;
border: none;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background: url('magnifier.png') top no-repeat;
}
```

That's very rough, but in the right direction.

Comment: +1, but make sure you wrap them both in a `position: relative;` container

Comment: can you share some example? sorry newbie here

Answer (score 0):

Add icon as a background image or if you want that to be clickable example: like google do float inputs and then to input text add border-radius on top and bottom part in left and in input submit add bordr radius on the right part in bottom and up, make them in same background and and in input submit add as a background img icon that you want. It will look same :)

Comment: If this is the solution than he will have to use `padding-left` or `padding-right` whichever side OP places the icon

Comment: Although that wouldn't be clickable.